# Is it safe to install Visual Studio 2019 preview side-by-side with Visual studio 2019 (Blazor wants the preview)?

Tags: visual-studio, preview, blazor

I want to try out Blazor and it wants Visual Studio 2019 Preview. Now, I already have Visual Studio 2019 (Professional) on my machine. It is safe to install the Preview version side-by-side?

Tried to find any help on forums, but didn't find any advice.

Comment: Daniel Roth, recommends to stick to the Visual Studio 2019 *Preview* channel https://twitter.com/danroth27/status/1113211173137027073

Comment: Thanks, seems that Preview is the way to go...

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I'll answer my question myself. Visual Studio 2019 Preview works fine side-by-side with released Visual Studio 2019. And I only got Blazor to install after I installed VS 2019 Preview.

Link to official [Blazor Getting Started Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) which specifically requires the Preview version (as of today)

Comment: You answered your own question but yes, I run both RTM and Preview side by side, no issues

Comment: It is the correct answer but without a link to an 'official' statement it is not of much use to this site.

Comment: Perfectly safe, and documented by Microsoft here https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/faq/

Comment: After some time I get error message "The Application is failed to sart because its side by side configuration is incorrect" while opening the visual studio 2019 preview.